# C# How to distribute columns as values to method parameters?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

Considering these classes:

```
public record ExpertiseDTO
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public ExpertiseDTO(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
public record SkillDTO// : ExpertiseDTO // Removed
{
    public ExpertiseDTO Expertise { get; init; }
    public string Potential { get; init; }
    public SkillDTO(ExpertiseDTO expertise, string potential)
        //: base(id, name)// removed
    {
        Expertise = expertise;
        Potential = potential;
    }
}
```

Before adding ranges, by giving a list of parameters as follow:

```
var newExpertises = new ExpertiseDTO[]
{
    new ExpertiseDTO (1, "myName"),
    new ExpertiseDTO (2, "myName1")
};
ExpertiseDTO.AddRange(newExpertises);
var newSkills = new SkillDTO[]
{
    new SkillDTO (newExpertises.Where(e => e.Name == "myName").Select(e => new ExpertiseDTO(e.Id, e.Name)).FirstOrDefault(), "My first potential."),
    new SkillDTO (newExpertises.Where(e => e.Name == "myName").Select(e => new ExpertiseDTO(e.Id, e.Name)).FirstOrDefault(), "My second potential."),
    new SkillDTO (newExpertises.Where(e => e.Name == "myName1").Select(e => new ExpertiseDTO(e.Id, e.Name)).FirstOrDefault(), "My third potential.")
};
SkillDTO.AddRange(newSkills);
```

How would I distribute the resulted list as values that would respectively take up the 2 parameters slot?

I tried

```
    new SkillDTO ((Id, Name) => newExpertises.Where(e => e.Name == "myName1").Select(e => new ExpertiseDTO(e.Id, e.Name)).FirstOrDefault(), "My third potential.")
```

-- Sorry for the confusion, I edited the code so that the classes no longer inherit but is composed as @fildor mentionned.
As of the .AddRange() it's going inside an IndexData, another class containing the classes. As fr this example I have decided to reduce (probably a bit too much I presume) of the code itself.
Now if that makes sense, I wonder if there is a way to distribute the resulted columns to fit the parameters, without passing the class itself as an input or using loops for that matter.

Comment: _"How would I distribute the resulted list as values that would respectively take up the 2 parameters slot?"_ I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Can you explain what your desired outcome would be?

Comment: One solution is (possibly) to write a constructor that takes an ExpertiseDTO as input. It's a little confusing as your code doesn't seem to make sense - neither ExpertiseDTO nor SkillDTO have AddRange() methods as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is also confusing because the data seems to suggest, SkillDTOs are N:1 related to ExpertiseDTO, yet they share their Id... so they don't have a unique key? It also appears to me as if there should be a has-a relation,  not a is-a.

Comment: I am not used to C#,  yet. Pressing Alt+enter editing the comments also posted an unfinished version also, my bad.

Comment: Using loops makes perfect sense here. I'm not sure why you would "not want to use loops". In any case, try that first if it works then you have some working code that demonstrates the desired result ... if the goal is to avoid loops then tackle that next.

Comment: Okay so with what you are saying, if I was to want individual class fields as input, the solution would be to loop through the columns in order to feed the constructor parameters.

Comment: Well, looking closer, another problem is you have "My first potential", "my second potential", "my third potential" hard coded in your code. Also, "myName" and "myName1" are hard coded. And for no apparent reason MyName gets to be "first" and "second" potentials but "MyName1" is the "third" potential. Just handling the strings for "first", "second", "third",,, (fourth, fifth?) ... is one issue. Then what happens if the names aren't "myName" or "myName1", and how to assign potential based on names ... this is all very messy.

Comment: But other than that, to answer your last question, basically ... "yes".